# Re-calculate CSS @keyframes (100vw and 100vh) after a window resize

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am working with an image [bouncing around](https://css-tricks.com/bounce-element-around-viewport-in-css/) inside a div.

This div has the size of the browser window.

(The div is sized `100vw` and `100vh` with CSS.)

**problem:**

Image floats **outside** div after resizing the browser window **smaller**.

The image bounces **before it hits the window's edge** when I make the browser window **bigger**.

*Conclusion: When I **resize the window** the div with the image bouncing inside **does not resize**.*

**Possible solution:**

Re-calculate the CSS keyframes (100vw and 100vh) after a window resize.

e.g. make browser window bigger -> box is bigger. make browser window smaller -> box is smaller.

**Question:**

Can I best solve my problem by:

1. reloading the whole page after a window resize by using jQuery?
2. resetting the `vw` and `vh` in CSS by detecting a window resize?
3. ???

**Update:**

What I've tried just now (no luck):

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
      $(".box").css('width','100%');
      $(".box").css('height','calc(100% - 160px)');
    });
```

**Update 02:**

I'm guessing that I probably have to somehow reset this after a window resize:

```
    @keyframes box {
      100% { transform: translateX( calc(100vw - 80px)); }
    }
    
    @keyframes smile {
      100% { transform: translateY( calc(100vh - 160px)); }
    }
```

I wish I could make the box fluidly follow the browser window width and height...

**Update 03:**

As 'A Haworth' pointed out in the comments below, this problem only occurs in Safari and not in Chrome.

**Update 04**

I am currently using using a temporary solution by 'A Haworth' and reload the animation on window resize only when the user is using Safari.

```
    const box = document.querySelector('.box');
    const smile = document.querySelector('.smile');

    if (
        navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && 
        navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1 && 
        navigator.userAgent.indexOf('CriOS/') == -1
        )  { 

            function resize() {
                box.style.animationName = 'none';
                smile.style.animationName = 'none';
                $('.smile').hide();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    box.style.animationName = 'box';
                    smile.style.animationName = 'smile';
                    $('.smile').fadeIn('slow');
                }, 1000);
            }
            window.onresize = resize;
            }
```

**Snippet:**

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.smile {
  height:  80px;
  width:  80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  animation: box 13s linear infinite alternate;
}

.smile {
  animation: smile 7s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes box {
  100% {
    transform: translateX( calc(100vw - 80px));
  }
}

@keyframes smile {
  100% {
    transform: translateY( calc(100vh - 80px));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
        <img class="smile" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/285/smiling-face-with-sunglasses_1f60e.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your example is weird: why does the size of the box changes and translates during the duration of the animation? Is that intentional?

Comment: it is. https://codepen.io/scottkellum/pen/BoZvjR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already using units that change automatically on viewport resizing you should not need to do any recalculation.

The only problem I could see is that there are scrollbars appearing which alter the 'edge'. You don't really want these so set the container for the whole thing to `overflow: hidden`. In this snippet the overall container is the body element.

It also sets the padding and margins to 0 otherwise it can look as though the emoji is hitting the top a little bit too soon.

UPDATE: tries to force animation to reset to new dimensions by removing it and then setting it again after a second (should be able to use requestAnimationFrame but not worked so far). This is for a trial on Safari where the problem occurs.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const smile = document.querySelector('.smile');
function resize() {
  box.style.animationName = 'none';
  smile.style.animationName = 'none';
  setTimeout(function () {
    box.style.animationName = 'box';
    smile.style.animationName = 'smile';
  }, 1000);
}
window.onresize = resize;
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.smile {
  height:  80px;
  width:  80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  animation: box 13s linear infinite alternate;
}

.smile {
  animation: smile 7s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes box {
  100% {
    transform: translateX( calc(100vw - 80px));
  }
}

@keyframes smile {
  100% {
    transform: translateY( calc(100vh - 80px));
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="box">
        <img class="smile" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/285/smiling-face-with-sunglasses_1f60e.png" />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The snippet is a little off, you are right. The page I am working with doesn't have the scrollbars and the offset. It's just that the box in which the image bounces, just doesn't fluidly follow the window resize -_- https://jordy.studio

Comment: I have resized in all directions and the bouncing seems fine. Can you explain a bit more what the problem is (or even a little video snippet of what you are seeing, because it must be different from what I am seeing). I'm on Windows 10 Chrome/Edge.

Comment: O wow you are right the whole thing works perfectly in Chrome! Yikes this did not cross my mind, but it seems it's a Safari problem.... ugh that is not a lot of fun....

Comment: So in Chrome the box resizes automatically, however in Safari the box stays the size it has on first load. I'm not sure if this makes my evening easier or harder haha thank you!

Comment: What device/OS are you on?

Comment: Mac - Safari (I'm now trying to add -webkit- and remove shorthands)

Comment: OK, I've just managed to reproduce what you are seeing on an iPad/Safari (by going from running the snippet to full page). It does indeed not resize, even when giving it a 'kick' by shanging from landscape to portrait rotating the device. This must be to do with the way Safari updates (or, rather, doesn't) the GPU's animation mustn't it? Will experiment further now I have a test case.

Comment: I'm thinking Safari does not like this bit: transform: translateX( calc(100vw - 80px));

Comment: Perhaps an easier solution is finding a jQuery way to bounce the icon around inside a fluid div.... But I'm not giving up yet!

Comment: A quick if dirty solution would be to reload on a resize event I think - not super-clean way of doing it but could be a start. A cleaner way would be to reset the animation on each resize, clear it for a frame or so then set it again.

Comment: Maybe I can use jQuery to clear the width and then set the width again on window resize, not sure if that's possible

Comment: Have added a couple of lines of JS to force reset of the animation on a resize. Seems to work at least on Safari on iPad IOS 14.

Comment: Thanks I have implement the temporary solution (and the code will be called only for Safari users only I think)

Comment: You can probably use requestAnimationFrame so as not to have the pause, or at least cut down on the timeout. Then I don't think the solution is temporary, I think you have to force Safari to reset the GPU settings.

Comment: True, I now hide the smile and fadeIn('slow') so it's not too bad. Does requestAnimationFrame make the smile continue its path from before the resize? That would be ace. Wish it was just as smooth and easy as in Chrome I don't really understand why it's not cross browser.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I've wrestled with that but can see no way of getting it to do so. Also can't find anything on the web to help, though we can't be the first people to try to suss this out! I toyed with the idea of listening for animationEnds but can't fathom the timing problems.

Answer (score -1):

you can use @media query to solve this problem, for more refer the below link
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: The width of the box in which the img bounces is set on first page load, I am trying to reset the size of the box after window resize. I feel with @media I'll have to set a fixed box width and height for every possible window size. Thousands? Hope I make sense! I could be wrong here....

Comment: @Jordy, you are right. You can never anticipate all possible viewport sizes using media query - it not just being the myriad of physical devices out there having different dimensions/aspect ratios, but a user on a windows-type machine can set the viewport to virtually anything.

Comment: if this is the case means, you can use flexbox or grid, which will be responsive.